# Python unable to access global variable in simple grade program

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, global-variables, global

I am trying to create a python program which I am facing an issue to access the global variable in function. Please check the code below and suggest to me what is wrong with the program.

All the global variable I am using is not been accessed by the last function `showGrades()`

**I am getting the error below:**
`NameError: name 'marks' is not defined`

```
def main():
  getInput()
  getGrades()
  showGrades()
def getInput():
    global Quiz,Ass,Test1,Test2,marks,Grade,GradePoint
    Quiz = float(input("Enter quiz overall marks out of 100 :"))
    Ass =  float(input("Enter assignment overall mark out of 100 :"))
    Test1 = float(input("Enter test1 overall mark out of 100 :"))
    Test2 = float(input("Enter test2 overall mark out of 100 :"))
def getGrades():
    marks = float((Quiz * 0.2) + (Ass * 0.2) + (Test1 * 0.3) + (Test2 * 0.3))
    if marks<=100 and marks>=94:
     Grade = "A+"
     GradePoint = 4.0
    elif marks<=93 and marks>=87:
      Grade = "A"
      GradePoint =3.7
    elif marks <= 86 and marks >= 80:
      Grade = "A-"
      GradePoint = 3.5
    elif marks <= 79 and marks >= 77:
     Grade = "B+"
     GradePoint = 3.2
    elif marks <= 76 and marks >= 73:
     Grade = "B"
     GradePoint = 3.0
    elif marks <= 72 and marks >= 70:
     Grade = "B-"
     GradePoint = 2.7
    elif marks <= 69 and marks >= 67:
     Grade = "C+"
     GradePoint = 2.3
    elif marks <= 66 and marks >= 63:
     Grade = "C"
     GradePoint =2.0
    elif marks <= 62 and marks >= 60:
     Grade = "C-"
     GradePoint = 1.7
    elif marks <= 59 and marks >= 50:
     Grade = "D"
     GradePoint =1.0
    else:
     Grade = "F"
     GradePoint = 0.0
def showGrades():
     print(f"your overall marks are:" , float(marks))
     print("Grade:" + str(Grade))
     print(f"GradePoint:" ,float(GradePoint))
main()
```

Comment: You need to use `global marks` at the beginning of every function where you use `marks` variable

Comment: Delete the screenshot, please. The text should be enough

Comment: Please include the error message as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `getInput` function, you declare that `marks` will be a global variable, but never actually assign it. Since the scope of the `global` keyword is only within that function, you actually never created a global variable `marks`.

Then in `getGrades`, you create another variable `marks`, which is local to `getGrades`, because you didn't declare `marks` as global in `getGrades`. This is why `showGrades` cannot find the variable `marks`; it is local to `getGrades`.

Try making declaring `marks` as a global inside of `getGrades`, and I'm pretty sure the problem will be fixed.

For more see: [What are the rules for local and global variables in Python?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)

---

Edit: To confirm my thinking I decided to do an experiment: I created a function where I declared, but never assigned a global variable. We then run the function, and use the built in `globals` function to check if `myglobalvariable` actually exists in the global scope

```
>>> def globaltest():
       global myglobalvariable

>>> globaltest()
>>> globals()

{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'globaltest': <function globaltest at 0x0000027E24B11EA0>}
```

We see from the output above that, as expected, `myglobalvariable` is not in the global scope.

Comment: Actually I am creating variable globally and assigning value in a function which needs to be done. Can you please correct it for me. I will accept your answer if it solved my problem. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that declaring a variable to be global in the context of one function (getInput) doesn't carry over to the next function (getGrades)

Comment: I am getting syntax error when I am declaring global marks = "test" I am getting equal to is syntax error

Comment: @JagdeeshKumar You're welcome. By the way, using global variables like this is generally bad practice. It's much better/simpler to just pass the variables as arguments to the functions....

Comment: @JagdeeshKumar I support what Evan Rosica just said now. It's not a good practice

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function `getGrades()`, I will suggests you place

```py
global mark, Grade, GradePoint
```

at the very first line. The problem should be solved then.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the "globals" declaration doesn't actually make the variable global.

You have to declare a variable in the correct "global" scope, and then use "global" to tell the function that there's a variable in the global scope and use that instead of locally creating one.

So before you call `main()`, declare all your global variables in the same indentation:

```
Quiz=None
Ass=None
Test1=None
Test2=None
marks=None
Grade=None
GradePoint=None

main()
```

Then in `showGrades()`, tell it the variables exist in the global scope:

```
def showGrades():
     global marks, Grade, GradePoint

     print(f"your overall marks are:" , float(marks))
     print("Grade:" + str(Grade))
     print(f"GradePoint:" ,float(GradePoint))
```

You will need to tell the function `getGrades()` to use the global variable it uses as well.

Comment: This wouldn't work. The `getGrades` function will not update the global variables, rather it 'll create new local varibles, so the values printed would be wrong. Also, to read a global variable, you don't need a global decleration. You only need it for writing global variables.